# "unassigning" a boost socket

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I created a UNIX/BSD socket that listens on a UDP multicast feed and since I want to use it with boost components later in my program, at some point, I did this :

```
boostSocket->assign(udp::v4(), static_cast<int>(*udpSocket));
```

boostSocket is a pointer to a boost Socket and udpSocket is a pointer to a UDP socket.

But I have trouble to correctly delete these two pointers.

How should I proceed? Is there a way of "unassigning" the boost socket before deleting it?

Comment: The boost socket doesn't know about udpSocket being a pointer. It gets an int. Any problem you might have deleting udpSocket is unrelated to boost. I suggest not having pointers to BSD sockets in the first place. A BSD socket is an int and can be passed by value anywhere.

Comment: It is not simply an "int", it is the socket descriptor... And If I delete the boost socket, if I try to delete the UDP socket after, it will fail.

Comment: Being a socket descriptor is not a justification to wrap it in a heap allocation. Is there any API that operates with heap-allocated pointers-to-socket-descriptors? Why do you think you need one?

Comment: "if I try to delete the UDP socket after, it will fail". This has nothing to do with it being a pointer to a socket descriptor. The boost socket doesn't know about pointers to socket descriptors. The failure is unrelated.